# CAML query and jQuery to retrieve last item's fields

Tags: jquery, caml-query, spservices

I want to get list item fields where its the last item that the same user created.
Then I want to populate the newform.aspx with some of these items.

I'm mainly stuck with the query and how to write it in the newform.aspx, I want to utlise jquery (client side).. I've added :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var userName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({  
        fieldName: "Name",debug: false
    });  


    $("input[title='Customer Name']").val(userName);  
    $("input[title='Customer Name'] ").attr('readonly', true);


});
```

code

Hope someone can help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [$().SPServices.SPGetLastItemId](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetLastItemId) function in [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/)? It will return the ID of the last item a user created in a list. That sounds like what you are after.